# How I can fix a Error in a commented line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver

I have one error in a commented line.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 41: 
Line 42:             //                //New sistem
Line 43:             //                //Add User  // ERROR
Line 44:             //                manager.AddAllUsersFromEpiServer();
Line 45:             //                //Associate to Admin Group
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Devcore.EpiCase.Controllers.BaseController.Initialize(RequestContext requestContext) in f:\Development\DevCore\EPiCase\modules\EpiCase\Controllers\BaseController.cs:43
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +388
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +832
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +188
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the comment?

Comment: So, it's not really about an error in a commented line ;-). Something has gone out of sync. Try rebuilding the whole thing

Comment: The error is in a line that is executing, however the assembly that the error is generated from is not the same one you're working with. This can happen in a web app when old versions of assemblies are in the ASP.net temp folder, and with other apps if the debug/release folder contains a previous version of the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dlls and pdbs are out of sync, a commented line can't throw an exceptions.

- Check your project references: Did you reference the output of a project in your solution, or did you add a direct reference to an .dll?
- Try "Clean solution" (right-click the solution) and rebuild the entire solution.
- Or you can try deleting everything in your bin folder and rebuild.